# How to setup android studio to use vuzix m100 smart glass sdk

Tags: android, installation, vuzix, vuzixm100

I am new in vuzix smart glasses. by searching here and there i am not getting any initial steps to go with vuzix.

1.I have register with vuzix as developer and got initial phase documentation.

2.How to setup vuzix sdk in android studio

Note: i don't want to use **wikitude sdk** for **vuzix glass**
Please provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

Install M100 sdk .
2. Android studio go to SDK Manager to see Vuzix Device Profiles is installed in SDK tool 
3.SDK updates Sites add this : http://vuzix.com/k79g75yXoS/addon.xml
4. M100 emulator should work for you in Android studio

Comment: I have done with your step 1 and 3. But in step 2,vuzix device profiles not shown in sdk manager. and i have add this link in add ons but it show a error. please help me out from this situtation.

Comment: @SurajBahadur, could you please tell me if solutions worked for you?

Comment: @pythonbuddha No, it did not help me at that time.